# How to read a continuous stream of output from a terminal with perl

Tags: perl, terminal

I understand that `backticks` can be used for retrieving the output of a command after it has finished execution but I don't know how to read outputs as they come in while the command is still executing or how to do this with multiple terminals at the same time.

The OS the script is runnning on is Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: `perldoc -f open` ... see "pipe opens".

Comment: and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open()-for-IPC

Comment: What do you intend to do with the ouput of multiple processes as it's coming?  You can `fork` and each child can deal with its own process but you can't sensibly print (for example) in real time; it would all end up interleaved and messed up.

Comment: @zdim I'm going to have the output written into a database

Comment: If you want to read from multiple children, you want [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run). Otherwise, you get into seriously complex code involving IO::Select or threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a question about Inter-Process Communication in Perl, then the [perlipc manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.htm) might be a good place to start. Specifically, in this case, the section on [Using `open()` for IPC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open()-for-IPC) seems useful.

Basically, you can use `open()` to open a handle onto a process which you can then read data from in the same way as you read data from any filehandle.

The example in the document uses `netstat`:

```
open(STATUS, "netstat -an 2>&1 |")
    || die "can't fork: $!";

while (<STATUS>) {
    next if /^(tcp|udp)/;
    print;
}

close STATUS        || die "bad netstat: $! $?";
```